# Items in kendo ListView jump to the top of the page on click upon the ListView Items to the first row with in the listView on ListView initialization

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-listview

In the Kendo Listview, I have a list of Items in the dataSource such that I have a scroll option to see the list of items. And upon click of any row, the entire listView jumps to the top of the first row with in the listView. This jump only happens on the first selection. Subsequent selections don't cause the listView to jump.

I tried setting the Navigatable option to false and the issue is solved. But I need the Navigatable option in my List View.

Is there any solution for this Issue?

Comment: I'm having a similar issue; does this happen in all browsers? I have only been able to replicate this issue in Internet Explorer.

Comment: Hi John, I'm facing this issue in Google Chrome as well. Need to test on other browsers too

Comment: I'm not sure if this helps you, but if any item in the listview is NOT shown on the screen (if you have to scroll down), the click event does not fire. Our listview only works for items that are visible on the screen (in internet explorer). Click events on listivew items that are lower in the html do not work, again, only for IE in our case.

Comment: Yes @john_h I just checked it. This happens to the items that are visible on the screen before we scroll down. This is happening on Chrome as well